# Android: ¿Cómo agrego un EditText dentro de un boton?

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext

Tengo un Activity que funciona como asistente, al hablar muestra el texto en pantalla y al nombrar 5 palabras especificas ejectura una función. Ejemplo: si digo la palabra "galeria", me manda a otro activity que contiene una galeria de imágenes.

Ahora bien, el asistente no solo debe funcionar solo hablando, sino que pueda opcionalmente usar el teclado, por el momento solo logro que muestre el teclado al presionar el icono del teclado con el código siguiente:

```
//oculta el teclado
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
 //muestra el teclado luego de presionar el icono

public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
//onClick del icono 
public void mostrarTeclado(View view) {
    hideSoftKeyboard(editText);
    showSoftKeyboard(editText);
}
```

y he agregado un EditText, pero este se  muestra en el activity por defecto y yo necesito que el EditText se muestre con el teclado luego de presionar el icono, tal como sucede con Google Assistant, pero no hallo la manera resolver eso.

He estado investigando en varios blogs y foros pero los únicos resultados que encuentro son de un Button dentro del EditText, y eso no aplica en mi problema, así que espero me puedan ayudar acá.

Comment: Estuve mirando y creo que lo que Google hace es ocultar la barra anterior y mostrar el edittext en su lugar y luego le aplica el foco o le hace 'focus' esto lleva a que el teléfono inmediatamente despliegue el teclado para escribir

Comment: en el xml al editText agregale  android:visibility="gone", y en el método showSoft editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Gracias armen, si funciono